# VirtualBox: Finding guest IP

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am currently hosting a Linux distro (the guest) inside a Windows machine (the host).

How can I find the IP address of the Linux distro from Windows?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current networking setup in both VirtualBox and the guest OS.

Comment: Turns out the IP's I had were actually valid and the issue was Firewall-related.

Comment: Good to hear. You got sucked into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452) it seems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line VBoxManage tool, e.g.:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get [vmname] "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

More generally (in case you have more adapters, IPv6, etc):

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get [vmname] "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/*"
```

[Source](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36592)

Comment: It returns `No value set!`, while the guest does have a working connection.

Comment: How are you setting the guest IP?  This won't work 100% of the time as mentioned in the comments in the source link.  If this doesn't work, I'm not sure of any other way to get the guest IP from the host (short of scanning your network).

Comment: I am not setting the IP manually anywhere. I looked around for it in the VirtualBox settings, nothing. It still works, though.

Comment: The question was more how your VM is set up - did you bridge an adapter, are you using IPv4, is there more than one adapter, etc.  Like I said, there are limitations to this method.

Comment: I am clueless about networking business, but I'll try and explain. The host machine is running on Wifi only. The guest was configured to use NAT (which gave it network but rendered it invisible to the host), so I tried to bridge it (no clue how it works) on the same Wireless adapter, no luck.

Comment: Turns out I can successfully ping the host system from the guest using the default IP like mentioned in your source. I still remain unable to ping the guest, though, which is my goal.

Comment: `VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate [vmname] "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/*"` will list all of the net-based properties.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Kenster.  Edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the VMWare OUI (first 6 characters of MAC address), you could do an `arp -a` and look for the IP address associated with the VMWare MAC address. Try something similar to:

```
arp -a | findstr "00-50-56"
```